# TypeError: slice indices must be integers

Tags: python, theano

It gives me the following error when test_model is called:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

But I'm calling test_model with an integer (a particular batch). Inputtest is a list of list of floats and labeltes is a vector of ints. I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
def optimize(learning_rate = 0.1,n_epochs = 1000, batch_size = 600):
    n_train_batches = len(inputt)//batch_size
    n_val_batches = len(inputsdev)//batch_size
    n_test_batches = len(inputstest)//batch_size
    rng = numpy.random.RandomState(1234)
    index = T.lscalar('index')
    x = T.ivector('x')
    y = T.ivector('y')
    classifier = Regression(x, n_in = 150, n_out = 24)
    cost = classifier.negative_log_likelihood(labelt)
    test_model = theano.function(inputs = [index], outputs =  classifier.errors(y),givens = { x: inputstest[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size], y : labeltes[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]})
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace

Comment: Can you explain your problem clearly?

Comment: What is `T.lscalar('index')`? Odds are, it's not `int`-like, and multiplying it by an `int` is not producing something `int`-like.

Comment: Is it labeltes  or labeltest?  Make sure it is not a typo.

Comment: Without more details it may be impossible to see what's going on. My guess is that `inputstest` and/or `labeltes` are not shared variables but they need to be. If they are plain numpy arrays then you can't slice a numpy array using a Theano symbolic index, i.e. the result of the symbolic expression `index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you will get a value looks like integer. I make two experiment to help you understand.

1.

```
list1 = [2,3]

index = '1'

print(list1[index])
```

output: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

2.

```
list1 = [2,3]

index = '1'

print(list1[int(index)])
```

output: 3

So you have to make sure the index you input to list or other data structure should be integer. But it will not always be integer. If you use dictionary, you should input string. It depends on the data structure you use.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: I don't believe that's the issue here - that issue can be fix with list(map(int, list1))  from your example. I believe the issue here with parameter givens.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I though they are similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Theano documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html) mentions that doing this

```
index = T.lscalar('index')
```

will return the index to a [mini]batch

I think the replacement:

```
x --> inputstest[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]
y --> labeltest[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]
```

in your graph is not working because you may need to use batch start and batch stop and you're not passing your learning rate to your function.