# creating ROI iteratively in OpenCV python

Tags: python, numpy

```py
import cv2

import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('R.jpg')

h,w,chan=img.shape

rh=h/5

rw=w/5

z={}

M = 5 # Number of patches along height and width

img_slice = img[:rh*M,:rw*M] # Slice out valid image data

z = img_slice.reshape(M,rh,M,rw,-1).transpose(0,2,1,3,4).reshape(M**2,rh,rw,-1)
```

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method.
```

can anyone give the solution for this?

Comment: Please edit your question to put code in code blocks and improve the description of your problem.

Comment: just google the error message. take the [tour], review [ask]. this site has rules.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738217/typeerror-slice-indices-must-be-integers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `print()` to see what you have in variables then you will see what is the problem

---

When you divide `/` then you create `float` values `rw`, `rh`
but `slice` (`img[:rh*M,:rw*M]`) needs `integer` values.

You can use `//` to get `integer` results

```
rh = h // 5

rw = w // 5
```

Or you can use `int()`

```
rh = int( h / 5 )

rw = int( w / 5 )
```

---

Full example

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('lenna.jpg')

h, w, chan = img.shape

rh = int(h / 5)
rw = int(w / 5)

print(rh, rw)

M = 5

img_slice = img[:rh*M,:rw*M]
```